# Запрос выводит не все категории

Tags: sql

Здравствуйте. Прошу прощения, если мой вопрос не корректный или я просто не обладаю достаточным количеством знаний для его решения, собственно, по этому и взываю к помощи знатоков.

Моя задача в следующем: Вывести список категорий, в которых опубликованы новости, содержащие в себе определённого актёра.

Таблицы: dle_category - Категории
dle_post - Новости

Ячейка actors содержит список актёров в виде сериализованного массива. 
Ячейка category строкового типа и в ней данные вида: "2, 5, 8", но может быть и просто число

Я написал вот такой запрос:

```
SELECT id, alt_name, name
FROM dle_category 
WHERE id IN ((SELECT category FROM dle_post WHERE actors LIKE '%Анджелина Джоли%'))
```

Он работает, но проблема в том, что выводит не все категории, в которых участвует новость, а только последнюю из списка (Пока только одна новость, удовлетворяющая запросу)

Ув. знатоки, прошу вас помочь мне составить правильный запрос.

Comment: А какой sql-сервер?

Comment: Подразумевается использование мощных серверов, если вы об этом. Конкретные характеристики не известны.

Comment: Вопрос о типе сервера касался вариантов расширения языка для работы с категориями-списками. Но правильней последовать совету @Drac5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вы используете сериализованные данные, то, наверное, и СУБД лучше использовать соответствующую - из семейства NoSQL.
Ненормализованные структуры в SQL будут вызывать у вас постоянные проблемы. 1000 записей - это совсем немного, чтобы одуматься. :-)
Что касается вопроса, то я могу предложить использовать вариант динамического SQL. Скажем, если результат подзапроса поместить в переменную [[@list](/users/3156/listka-net)](/users/3156/listka-net) (не знаю, какая у вас СУБД), тогда примерно так:

```
execute "SELECT id, alt_name, name
FROM dle_category 
WHERE id IN (" + @list + ")"
```

Comment: СУБД мускул

Comment: Тогда вам сюда: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html

Но лучше нормализовать. :-)

Answer (score 2):

У вас поле Категория не нормализовано. Может быть стоит задуматься об отдельной таблице вида:

- Номер новости
- Категория

, где у каждой новости может быть несколько категорий. Тогда работа пойдет проще. Пара джоинов и всё готово.

Comment: Спасибо конечно за совет, но это не то. В таблице новостей уже больше 1000 записей и менять структуру БД нет возможности. Поэтому вот и мучаюсь с этим запросом

Comment: Ну если уже 1000 записей на неизвестном (засекреченном?) сервере... google, если спросите, выдаст кучу ссылок на тему 'sql split' (в том числе и на stackoverflow.com, например http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647/split-string-in-sql). Там Вы можете найти немало вариантов UDF (user defined function), созданных для разбиения строки, содержащей разделители (в Вашем случае -- запятые) на части (слова). Применив эту функцию к dlr_post.category, вы можете найти в полученном результате свою dle_category.id

Comment: Извините, но 1000 записей - это ничто. Распарсить их с помощью php/python/perl - дело 5 минут. Да и выше подсказывают как это с помощью SQL делать.